# What was the most common and generic word used in classic Latin that meant "to speak" or "to talk"?

Tags: word-request, verbs, word-comparison, spanish

Nowadays in Spanish the verb used for "to speak" or "to talk" is *hablar*, which comes directly from Latin ***fābŭlor***, meaning:

> **1** to talk familiarly, to chat, to converse
>   **2** to invent a story, to make up a fable

In fact this verb also derived into today's *fábula* (English: 'fable'). Nonetheless, I have seen some other options in an old Spanish-Latin dictionary from 1495 when I looked up *hablar*:

> ***collŏquor***: "to talk, to speak to or to speak with", "to talk together or to talk over", "to converse"
>   ***allŏquor***: "to speak to", "to address, to harangue, to make a speech (to)"
>   ***ēlŏquor***: "to speak out, utter"

And in another Spanish dictionary from 1734 the verb *hablar* is translated into Latin as:

> ***for***: "to speak, to talk", "to say"
>    ***sermōcĭnor***: "to discuss, to argue with wit, to treat scholarly", "to talk"
>   ***lŏquor***: "to speak", "to tell", "to mention", "to say, to utter", "to phrase"

I would say that the verb I am looking for is indeed *fābŭlor* as it is the verb that derived into today's most used (and generic) verb in Spanish meaning "to speak" or "to talk", and it seems it was used for casual chats with family and friends, but as there are other options, I would like to ask:

- What was the most basic, generic and commonly used word that meant "to speak" or "to talk" in the Latin language?
- What were the differences between the mentioned options? Are there any other ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Dico** is by far the most frequent semantically related verb, but it [means](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Ddico2) *to say* (and in some contexts could be read as to speak in specific senses, but not to talk).

Among the ones meaning talk and/or speak, the verb **loquor** is way more frequent than its nearest contender as per the available corpora (a sample search for [loquor](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=exact&lookup=loquor&lang=la) gives 11k results, [*colloquor*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=start&lookup=colloqu&lang=la) and [*fabulor*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=start&lookup=colloqu&lang=la) about 100, *fabulo* redirects to fabulor, which means that it's probably the less common alternative).

*Eloquor* is less frequent ([~ 1700](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=start&lookup=eloqu&lang=la) hits) than loquor, yet more than the others, but it has a number of more specific [meanings](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Deloquor): *to speak out, speak plainly, to utter; to pronounce, declare, state, express*.

Regarding *for*, my response is necessarily less informed, since I'm not very familiar with it.

- L&S says it is mostly poetic, and does not mention to talk among [its meanings](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfor).
- The respective [search](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=exact&lookup=for&lang=la) gives a maximum frequency about 2.5 as high as that of loquor, but a minimum 1/10th as high. The problem is that being such a short and irregular verb, a bunch of other words get mixed up in the results (e.g. [*fas*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfas), [*fere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfere)).
- My gut feeling is that it is mainly (if not only) Classical, and got lost with the centuries.